# Add numeric keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard

It's possible to set or add numeric keyboard without `+, -, . sign` in android app?

I want only `0-9, backspace and enter` keys?

I tried with

```
inputType="number" 
setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line on your code:

- input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);

this will show **only** the numeric keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Just use this line your XML file

For Example In my Edit Text

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtMobileNo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnSignup"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background_edittext"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username_icon"
    android:hint="@string/mobile_no_hint"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="10"
     />
```

[image: ScreenShot Of Numeric KeyBoard]